# AWS V1 ClientConfiguration to V2 ClientOverrideConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-glue

I'm refactoring a bunch of code from AWS V1 sdk to V2 and am stuck creating the proxy configuration for a GlueClient.

V1 code:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(8443);
clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
```

V2 code:

```
ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder(). ??? .build();
```

I can't find any good examples of how to do this. There do not seem to be any proxy options in the replacement class for V2

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using the Java SDK based on classnames, in which case you set the proxy configuration on the `HTTPClientBuilder`. Here's an example with the default (Apache) client-builder, taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kdgregory/d6bed8c245ce326d461aeb65825358d2), which shows a complete program and compares it to the V1 proxy configuration.

```
ProxyConfiguration config = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
                            .endpoint(new URI("http://localhost:3128"))
                            .addNonProxyHost("169.254.169.254")
                            .useSystemPropertyValues(Boolean.FALSE)
                            .build();

ApacheHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                                         .proxyConfiguration(config);

StsClient client = StsClient.builder()
                   .httpClientBuilder(clientBuilder)
                   .build();
```

You might also be interested in the ways to automatically configure a proxy via environment variables or system properties, which I've documented [here](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/blob/trunk/docs/client.md#using-a-proxy). TL;DR: it's a hot mess.